# what is the efficient way to collect computed results in python and turn it to a dataframe to make some analysis?

Tags: python, pandas, calculated-field

I am doing some computing on a dataset using loops. Then, based on random event, I am going to compute some float number(This means that I don't know in advance how many floats I am going to retrieve). I want to save these numbers(results) in a some kind of a list and then save them to a dataframe column ( I want to have these results for each iteration in my loop and save them in a column so I can compare them, meaning, each iteration will produce a "list" of results that will be registred in a df column)

example:

```
for y in range(1,10):
 for x in range(1,100):
  if(x>random number and x<y):
   result=2*x
```

I want to save all the results in a dataframe columns by combination x,y. For example, the results for x=1,y=2 in a column then x=2,y=2 in column ...etc   and the results are not of the same size, so I guess that I'll use fillna.

Now I know that I can create an empty dataframe with max index and then fill it result by result, but I think there's a better way to do it!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You want to take advantage of the efficiency that `numpy` and `pandas` give you. If you use `numpy.where`, you can set the value to `nan` when the `if` statement is `False`, and otherwise you can execute your formula:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0) # so you can reproduce my result, you can remove this in practice
x = list(range(10))
y = list(range(1, 11))
random_nums = 10 * np.random.random(10)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : x, 'y': y})
# the first argument is your if condition
df['new_col'] = np.where((df['x'] > random_nums) & (df['x'] < df['y']), 2*df['x'], np.nan)
print(df)
```

Here, `random_nums` generates an entire `np.ndarray` of random numbers to compare with. This gives

```
   x   y  new_col
0  0   1      NaN
1  1   2      NaN
2  2   3      NaN
3  3   4      NaN
4  4   5      NaN
5  5   6      NaN
6  6   7     12.0
7  7   8      NaN
8  8   9      NaN
9  9  10     18.0
```

This is especially faster if your formula (here, `2*x`) is relatively quick to compute.

Comment: @Mass111 In that case you should be able to use the same process. If you have two columns `x` and `y`, then `df['x'] * df['y']` returns `df['x'][0] * df['y'][0], df['x'][1] * df['y'][1], ...`. This is called element-wise multiplication. In general, you want to use this **vectorized form**: `df['x'] * df['y']` because this calls C code, which is much, much faster than the python code you write in a for loop.